# Centre and origin of Circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on this question that needs the origin of a circle:

> a) Show that the circle $x^2+y^2-10x-8y+25=0$ touches the x-axis, and find the coordinate of the point of contact
>   b) find the equation of the other tangent from the origin to this circle.

Pls What's the difference between the origin of a circle and the centre of a circle.
Or are they the same?

Comment: I've never met a circle with an "origin" before; they have all had centres though.

Comment: Could you quote the entire question? 'Origin' should refer to a coordinate system.

Comment: Here is the question:

Show that the circle $x^2+y^2-10x-8y+25=0$ touches the x-axis, and find the coordinate of the point of contact
b.) find the equation of the other tangent from the origin to this circle.

The problem is with the second part of the question.

Comment: There is no ambiguity:  `the other tangent from the origin to this circle` means the tangent different from  the $x$-axis  which can be drawn from the origin of the axes of coordinates. Nowhere  ‘the origin of the circle’ is mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in my comment, you misinterpreted the question. You have to find the equation of the tangent which passes through the origin of the axes.

This is easy so solve geometrically: if $\varphi$ is the polar angle of the centre of the circle, the tangent sought after has polar angle $2\varphi$,so that its slope is
$$p=\tan2\varphi=\frac{2\tan\varphi}{1-\tan^2\varphi}=\frac{\dfrac85}{1-\dfrac{16}{25}}=\frac{40}9.$$

Comment: Oh! I have misinterpreted the question. Agreed.

Comment: Never read too fast! ;o) Thad said, there may be an origin  on a circle, choosing an arbitrary point on it for the origin of the curvilinear abscissa. It's the only  context in which I've heard of the origin of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Part a)**

Putting $y=0$ gives $(x-5)^2=0$ which confirms that the $x-$axis is tangential to the circle, with $T(5,0)$ as the tangential point.

**Part b)**

The equation of the circle can be written as

$$(x-5)^2+(y-4)^2=16$$
i.e. it has radius $4$ and centre $C(5,4)$.

Let $\theta=\angle TOC$, i.e. $\tan\theta=\frac 45$. Hence $\tan 2\theta=\frac {2\frac 85}{1-\frac {16}{25}}=\frac {40}9$

By symmetry about $OC$, if the other tangent point is $T'$ then $\angle T'OC=\angle TOC$, hence the other tangent passing through $O$ is given by $y=x\tan 2\theta$, i.e. $y=\frac {40}9x$.